# Make C# foreach prints once

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

I am stuck with this smart problem. I can not find a customizable solution.
I am trying to print my `List of Lists` using `foreach`. This is the code:

```
int i = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var subList in result)
{
 i++;
 Console.WriteLine(sb.Append("******\n").Append("Group ").Append(i).Append(" - ").
                    Append("Number of students: ").Append(subList.Count()).Append("\n").Append("   
               Name:").Append("\n"));
 var exp = subList.GetEnumerator();
 while (exp.MoveNext())
 {
  Console.WriteLine(sb.Append("         ").Append(exp.Current.ToString()).Append("\n"));
 }
}
```

I am trying to get this result (for examle):

```
Group 1 - Number of students: 3
   Name:
    this
    is
    a
Group 2 - Number of students: 3
  Name:
    test
    again
    and-again
```

and so on.
The problem is that I am getting always this (its prints each time from `foreach`):

```
Console.WriteLine(sb.Append("******\n").Append("Group ").Append(i).Append(" - ").
         Append("Number of students: ").Append(subList.Count()).Append("\n").Append("   
             Name:").Append("\n"));
```

like this:

```
******
Group 1 - Number of students: 3
   Name:
******
Group 1 - Number of students: 3
   Name:
         this
******
Group 1 - Number of students: 3
   Name:
         this
         is
******
Group 1 - Number of students: 3
   Name:
         this
         is
         a
```

and so on for the rest of the list. Can anyone guide me to resolve this.
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown us what `result` looks like, so it would be difficult to form an opinion about your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `Console.WriteLine` for each call to `sb.Append`. You need to fully build your string and then print it all at once

```
int i = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var subList in result)
{
 i++;
 sb.Append("******\n")
   .Append("Group ")
   .Append(i)
   .Append(" - ")
   .Append("Number of students: ")
   .Append(subList.Count())
   .Append("\n")
   .Append("Name:")
   .Append("\n");

 foreach(var exp in subList)
 {
  sb.Append("         ").Append(exp.ToString()).Append("\n");
 }
}
Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: quite simply. Thanks